# Resize right div before left in a flex form

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a form with 2 blocs of inputs which are contain in a tab that can be resized by drag & drop mouse. The application is desktop only, so I don't think media queries can help here.
By default there is enough space to have the two bloc on the same line, but if the tab get smaller I would like to resize first the right bloc before it goes beneath if not enough space.
Here's a small schema from what I want:

[image]

I think flex is the solution but currently both blocs are resizing together before going underneath, which is not what I want. I did a small JSFiddle to experiment: https://jsfiddle.net/g6kypur7/4/

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
  flex-basis: 47%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.input {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </div>
</div>
```

Anybody can help plz ?

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) ? You can use different sm/md/etc. sizes to control your resizing.

Comment: sm/md.. are used for device. Here I'm always on a desktop, but within a tab that is resizable by mouse (didn't have the motivation to set up the resize on the snippet)